# exported image from Highcharts has a blank square on up-left corner

Tags: asp.net, image, highcharts, export

I have been working on exporting Highchart to JPEG image. I have downloaded the asp.net code for exporting.

Everything works fine, just the image exported has a blank square on the up-left corn. (sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post an image) 
However, the exact same code, but I change the export url to "http://export.highcharts.com/", then export to image, it looks fine.

So I am assuming nothing is wrong with my code? unless I have missed some configurations? Can anybody help thanks.

Comment: Just guessing here, but is it a trial version that only works when pointed to the `highcharts.com` domain?

Comment: Do you use your own exporitng server like phantom js or something different ?